# React display json key and value

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to read a JSON data :
and i got this error
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to the index type
my data is local josn file and I am importing them   :

```
{
    "user": {
      "name": "foo",
      "location": "India",
       
    },
    "product": {
        "name": "Iphone",
        "version": "12",
      }
}
```

i am displaying like this

```
const data =data;

            <div>
              {Object.keys(data.user).map((key,i) => (
                <p key={i}>
                    <span>{key}</span>
                    <span>{data.user[key]}</span>
                </p>))}
           </div>
```

every thing is working except for this line :

```
<span>{data.user[key]}</span>
```

it gives error :

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to the index type
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
```

Comment: Seems there is no error. I've tried it in Codesanbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the keys to their keys in the object like so:

```js
{(Object.keys(data.user) as (keyof typeof data.user)[]).map((key, i) => (
  <p key={i}>
    <span>{key}</span>
    <span>{data.user[key]}</span>
  </p>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast `key` to type any:

```js
<span>{data.user[key as any]}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `type` for data like below

`const data: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } }`

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hopper-2vowh?file=/src/App.tsx:205-212

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of objects that contain strings, you can do what I did.

```
const rows: { [key: string]: string }[] = [
    {
        id: 'load-balancer-1',
        name: 'Load Balancer 1',
        rule: 'Round robin',
        status: 'Starting',
        other: 'Test',
        example: '22',
    },
    ...
];
```